# Get list of users with the "send on behalf of" permission

Tags: permissions, docusignapi

Using the V2 DocuSign REST API, is it possible to get a list of users who have the "send on behalf of" and "account wide" permission?

Looking through the [docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20Campaign%20Email%201%20-%20Key%20Information&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua#REST%20API%20References/REST%20API%20References.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____0), I see that the [Get User List](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20Campaign%20Email%201%20-%20Key%20Information&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua#REST%20API%20References/Get%20User%20List.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____113) method does not return any permission info. The [Get User Information](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20Campaign%20Email%201%20-%20Key%20Information&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua#REST%20API%20References/Get%20User%20Information.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____115) method returns a little more but nothing permission specific, other than a `permissionProfileId` for each `group`.

So is it possible to get permission info with user data? Or is there a method I can call using the `permissionProfileId` to check if a user has those permissions?

What I am ultimately trying to do is get a list of users who are able to use the "Send on behalf of" feature which requires the "send on behalf of" and "account-wide rights" permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all users and their User Settings with below rest method as an DS Admin:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[accountid]/users/?additional_info=true

Sample output below:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "userName": "DocuSignTest2 User-2",
      "userId": "b67aa83b-2b3e-4669-a897-89e44b5724c2",
      "userType": "CompanyUser",
      "isAdmin": "False",
      "userStatus": "Created",
      "uri": "/users/b67aa83b-2b3e-4669-a897-89e44b5724c2",
      "email": "youremail@yourdoman.com",
      "firstName": "DocuSignTest2",
      "lastName": "User-2",
      "userSettings": [
        {
          "name": "canManageAccount",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "canSendEnvelope",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "locale",
          "value": "en"
        },
        {
          "name": "canSendAPIRequests",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "apiAccountWideAccess",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "enableVaulting",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "vaultingMode",
          "value": "none"
        },
        {
          "name": "enableTransactionPoint",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "enableSequentialSigningAPI",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "enableSquentialSigningUI",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "enableDSPro",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "powerFormAdmin",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "powerFormUser",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "canEditSharedAddressbook",
          "value": "use_private_and_shared"
        },
        {
          "name": "canManageTemplates",
          "value": "create"
        },
        {
          "name": "enableSignOnPaperOverride",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "enableSignerAttachments",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "allowSendOnBehalfOf",
          "value": "false"
        },
        {
          "name": "allowRecipientLanguageSelection",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "name": "selfSignedRecipientEmailDocument",
          "value": "include_pdf"
        }
      ],
      "sendActivationOnInvalidLogin": "false",
      "enableConnectForUser": "false",
      "groupList": [
        {
          "groupId": "128693",
          "groupName": "Everyone",
          "groupType": "everyoneGroup"
        }
      ],
      "workAddress": {
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "",
        "stateOrProvince": "",
        "postalCode": "",
        "phone": "",
        "country": ""
      },
      "homeAddress": {
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "",
        "stateOrProvince": "",
        "postalCode": "",
        "phone": "",
        "country": ""
      }
    },
    [rest removed for sake of example]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not one call that can complete this task.

My recommendation is to put all of these users in a Group and then you can query who is in the group through the API.

Example get list of user's per group:

```
GET https://{server}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/groups/{groupId}/users
```

If you want to audit the group or see who you need to move into the group you can get a list of users and then look at user details per user (loop through programmaticaly).

Example get user settings to check `userSettings->allowSendOnBehalfOf` :

```
GET https://{server}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}
```

Comment: oh, I guess I should have tried that last method out. `allowSendOnBehalfOf` isn't mentioned in the example response as it  is just generalized to be `name` and `value` for the `userSettings`. That should work for me, thanks!

Comment: No problem, just remember that there are hourly API limits (1000). So if you have 10000 users, you'd have to space this over a timeframe :)

Comment: Ok so I am finding that if I include `?additional_info=true` on the Get User List method, it does return everything I need, which is permissions in the `userSettings`. So it does appear that I **can** do this in one method call.

Comment: iHan, correct, so I updated the below with the Answer for you and others.

Comment: Completely forgot about additional_info=true, you guys are correct :)